# Having both manual and automatic functions for an led

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, esp32

So I have come to a problem where I can not get out of a loop after I'm in it. My project is to have two functions, one for manual and another for automatic which will run forever, but I want that when I am in automatic, I will be able to get out by clicking the manual button on my phone. I don't know if that makes sense, but I really need help.

```
//Program to control LED (ON/OFF) from ESP32 using Serial Bluetooth

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <BluetoothSerial.h> //Header File for Serial Bluetooth, will be added by default into Arduino

BluetoothSerial ESP_BT; //Object for Bluetooth

int incoming;
int yellow_led = 13;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //Start Serial monitor in 9600
  ESP_BT.begin("ESP32_LED_Control"); //Name of your Bluetooth Signal
  Serial.println("Bluetooth Device is Ready to Pair");

  pinMode (yellow_led, OUTPUT);//Specify that LED pin is output
}



void automatic()
{
  while (incoming != 51)
  {
    digitalWrite(yellow_led, HIGH);
    ESP_BT.println("LED turned ON");

    delay(1000);

    digitalWrite(yellow_led, LOW);
    ESP_BT.println("LED turned OFF");

    delay(1000);
  }
}

void manual()
{
    if (incoming == 49)
    {
      digitalWrite(yellow_led, HIGH);
      ESP_BT.println("LED turned ON");    
    }
    else if(incoming == 48)
    {
      digitalWrite(yellow_led, LOW);
      ESP_BT.println("LED turned OFF");    
    }
}

void loop() {

  if (ESP_BT.available()) //Check if we receive anything from Bluetooth
  {
    incoming = ESP_BT.read(); //Read what we recevive 
    Serial.print("Received:"); Serial.println(incoming);

    if (incoming == 51) //#3
        {
          ESP_BT.println("In Manual Mode");
          manual();
        }

    else if (incoming == 52) //#4
        {
          ESP_BT.println("In Automatic Mode");
          automatic();
        }
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? "Need help" is not very descriptive.

Comment: Your automatic function is an infinite loop.  Since incoming never changes inside the loop you'll be stuck there forever.  You need to get a new value for incoming on each turn of that while loop.  Or better yet, ditch the while loop and let the loop function keep calling that function over and over if you want to keep running it over and over.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop in the automatic function is unnecessary. You're already looping infinitely within `loop()` so that should be enough. Adding another loop, even though at first may seem like it will break, turns out to be an infinite loop. I'll get to that in a second.

So all you need to do is get rid of the `while` loop and it should work. However, this works only if you are guaranteed to have an `incoming` value for each time in the loop, which is what seems like from your code.

Another problem I see here is that if you enter say `manual()`, there is nothing really that changes the value of `incoming`, you're bound to have `51` as you're reusing the previous value and nothing no desired code path will be triggered.
Same also applies to `automatic()`, I hope you can see how that loop becomes infinite because of this.

So you also need something on the following lines.

```
void manual()
{
    if (!ESP_BT.available())
        return;
    incoming = ESP_BT.read();
    if (incoming == 49)
    {
        digitalWrite(yellow_led, HIGH);
        ESP_BT.println("LED turned ON");    
    }
    else if(incoming == 48)
    {
        digitalWrite(yellow_led, LOW);
        ESP_BT.println("LED turned OFF");    
    }
}
```